# Using python type hints with numba

Tags: python, types, numba

From the numba website:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def f(x, y):
    # A somewhat trivial example
    return x + y
```

Is there a way to have numba use python type hints (if provided)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes and no. You can simply use the normal python syntax for annotations (the `jit` decorator will preserve them). Building on your simple example:

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def f(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    # A somewhat trivial example
    return x + y

>>> f.__annotations__
{'return': int, 'x': int, 'y': int}
>>> f.signatures  # they are not recognized as signatures for jit
[]
```

However to explicitly (enforce) the signature it must be given in the `jit`-decorator:

```
from numba import int_

@jit(int_(int_, int_))
def f(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    # A somewhat trivial example
    return x + y

>>> f.signatures
[(int32, int32)]  # may be different on other machines
```

There is as far as I know no automatic way for `jit` to understand the annotations and build its signature from these.

Comment: Seems like it should be pretty simple to roll your own decorator that extracts the type annotations, translates them to numba, and then wraps the function by calling jit with the translated types.

Comment: @Mike If it was that simple, why doesn't numba have it already? It is a pretty huge project. Therefore I assume this is very hard to safely do in edge-cases.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is Just In Time compilation, you must execute the function to generate the signatures

```
In [119]: f(1.0,1.0)
Out[119]: 2.0

In [120]: f(1j,1)
Out[120]: (1+1j)

In [121]: f.signatures
Out[121]: [(float64, float64), (complex128, int64)]
```

A new signature is generated each time the previous doesn't fit the data.